# trying to read an attribute from an xml file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am stuck on reading a attribute from a xml file.

A sample of the xml file is this:

```
<products products_num="358">
  <product product_id="71166" type="main" product_counter="1">
   <product_id>71122</product_id>
   <sku>TN245</sku>
   <model>37TN245Y</model>
   <name>PRODUCT NAME</name>
   <manufacturer>OEM</manufacturer>
   <url>http://www.mysite.xx/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=71122</url>
   <product_categories prod_cat_num="1">
    <category_path category_id="48">CATEGORY -&gt; CATEGORY</category_path>
   </product_categories>
   <mpn>-</mpn>
   <barcode>-</barcode>
   <date_added>2021-03-17 15:16:26</date_added>
   <last_modified>2021-03-17 15:16:26</last_modified>
   <description><![CDATA[DESCRTION]]></description>
   <images>
    <image_url type="main">http://www.mysyte.xx/image/catalog/product/10061.jpg</image_url>
   </images>
   <price tax_rate="24%" customer_perc="50.00%" currency="EUR">
    <price_original>7.9300</price_original>
    <price_with_perc>11.8950</price_with_perc>
    <price_with_tax>14.7498</price_with_tax>
   </price>
   <instock>Y</instock>
   <shipping>Y</shipping>
   <minimum_quantity>1</minimum_quantity>
   <availability status="In Stock" quantity="32" id="7"/>
  </product>
 </products>
```

I am using the following code

```
$family = $this->getCurrentElement($object->product_categories->product_categories);
$this->_product['attribute'] = $family['category_id'];
```

I can read every other element of the xml but not category_id. So I am trying to capture the string category_id with no luck.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: so you're wanting to update the xml?

Comment: Try `$family->category_path['category_id']` (since `$family` contains `product_categories` and the id is on the `category_path` element inside it)

Comment: What does `$this->getCurrentElement` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I tried code in different format, if it is fine you can follow!

```
<?php
$string = '<products products_num="358">
  <product product_id="71166" type="main" product_counter="1">
   <product_id>71122</product_id>
   <sku>TN245</sku>
   <model>37TN245Y</model>
   <name>PRODUCT NAME</name>
   <manufacturer>OEM</manufacturer>
   <url>http://www.mysite.xx/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=71122</url>
   <product_categories prod_cat_num="1">
    <category_path category_id="48">CATEGORY -&gt; CATEGORY</category_path>
   </product_categories>
   <mpn>-</mpn>
   <barcode>-</barcode>
   <date_added>2021-03-17 15:16:26</date_added>
   <last_modified>2021-03-17 15:16:26</last_modified>
   <description><![CDATA[DESCRTION]]></description>
   <images>
    <image_url type="main">http://www.mysyte.xx/image/catalog/product/10061.jpg</image_url>
   </images>
   <price tax_rate="24%" customer_perc="50.00%" currency="EUR">
    <price_original>7.9300</price_original>
    <price_with_perc>11.8950</price_with_perc>
    <price_with_tax>14.7498</price_with_tax>
   </price>
   <instock>Y</instock>
   <shipping>Y</shipping>
   <minimum_quantity>1</minimum_quantity>
   <availability status="In Stock" quantity="32" id="7"/>
  </product>
 </products>';                                                                       
                                          
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo($xml->product->product_id)."<br/>";
echo($xml->product->product_categories->category_path[@category_id])."<br/>";
echo($xml->product->sku)."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: The xml is external. I tried to adapt the code like this $family = $this->getCurrentElement($object->product_categories->category_path);
        $this->_product['attribute'] = $family['category_id']; but no joy...

Comment: What I find strange is that using $family = $this->getCurrentElement($object->product_categories);
        $this->_product['category_id'] = $family['prod_cat_num'];   works. but $family = $this->getCurrentElement($object->product_categories->category_path);
        $this->_product['category_id'] = $family['category_id']; does not

Comment: $family = $this->getCurrentElement($object->product->product_categories->category_path[@category_id]);? can you check it works from yourside??what i observer is _product is not available in your xml?

Comment: Hi, not working I get Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Try this code: $object = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$family = $object->product;
echo($family->product_id)."<br/>";
echo($family->model)."<br/>";
echo($family->product_categories[@prod_cat_num])."<br/>";
echo($family->product_categories->category_path[@category_id])."<br/>";
echo($family->sku);